# Creating hmac-sha-256 signature in Node js

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptojs, hmac

I have been trying to use a web service which requires a signature on every request. The document that I am following has been written in c#. The code is as follows.

stringToSign = "abc";

```
static string ComputeSignature(string stringToSign)
        {
            string secret = "<secret>";
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(secret)))
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToSign);
                var hashedBytes = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to replicate the same code in Node and I could come up with the following code so far using crypto:

```
const ComputeSignature = (stringToSign) => {
  let secret = "<secret>";
  var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(stringToSign).digest('base64');
  return hash;
}
```

The signatures that get generated are different and thus the requests are failing. Can someone tell me what changes I should make to the node code to make this work and what the problem with the above code is?

TIA!

Comment: In the NodeJS code, the Base64 decoding of `secret` is missing in the `createHmac()` call: `Buffer.from(secret, 'base64')`